# Bonobo Git hook

Tags: git, githooks

Хочу чтобы Jenkins собирал проект после push на git сервере, создал hook post-recive в папке hooks в репозитории (использую Bonobo Git Server) на сервере:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec curl -u login:pass http://vpn:8080/job/NavisWorksBatchConverter%20(DEV)/build?token=NavisWorksBatchConverter_DEV
```

ссылку мне дал Jenkins.
Почему этот hook не работает?
Пробовал без `exec`, тоже не работает, а вот если я с сервера из консоли запускаю эту команду то Jenkins собирает проект.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ваш git server и Jenkins хостятся на одном сервере? Если нет, то, возможно, git server не может разресолвить имя `vpn`.

Comment: да оба сервиса хостятся ни одном сервере

Answer (score 1):

А пробовали указывать абсолютный путь до curl?

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/curl --user user:pass -s \

http://vpn:8080/job/NavisWorksBatchConverter%20(DEV)/build?token=NavisWorksBatchConverter_DEV
```

Comment: попробовал. не работает...а как вообще проверить отрабатывают ли хуки? Bonobo server может где лог ведет???

Comment: Bonobo server на винде? О_О

Comment: да он на винде....

Comment: Making cUrl Available to the Git Server - https://blog.dangl.me/archive/configure-git-hooks-on-bonobo-git-server-in-windows/